# problem in passing data to url using GET method

Tags: python

```
        params = urllib.urlencode(data)
        headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                   "Accept": "text/plain",
                   }

        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(self.base_url)
        conn.request('GET', url, params, headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        response_data = response.read()
        conn.close()
```

Using above code I am passing data to `url`. When method is `POST` every thing is fine. But Method is `'GET'` i am not getting any data in response. 
But when i am trying

```
        url_data = urllib.urlopen(url)
        url_data.read()
```

Then I am getting proper result.What could be the reason? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using "GET" , the parameters should be really placed along with the URL - the "body" argument (to which ou are passing "params") is only used in post requests -
In other words, try this instead:

```
conn.request('GET', url + "?" + params, None, headers)
```